# Is my conceptual understanding pertaining to heat & temperature correct?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, terminology, definition

From what I've understood:

- Heat is the total sum of translational energy possessed by individual atoms in an object.
- Temperature is the average  translational energy possessed by individual atoms in an object.

Is my understanding correct? If not, what would be a concise way of accurately defining these two terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heat is a type of energy *transfer* from one system to another, rather than an internal energy of any given system ('thermal energy' might be a good term for what you're thinking of). In *An Introduction to Thermal Physics* by Daniel Schroeder, p. 18 says:

> **Heat** is defined as any spontaneous flow of energy from one object to another caused by a difference in temperature between the objects
>   ... **Work**, in thermodynamics, is defined as any other transfer of
>   energy into or out of a system. You do work on a system whenever you
>   push on a piston, stir a cup of coffee, or run current through a
>   resistor. In each case, the system's energy will increase, and usually
>   its temperature will too. But we don't say the object is being
>   "heated," because the flow of energy is not a spontaneous one caused
>   by a difference in temperature. Usually, with work, we can identify
>   some "agent" (possibly an inanimate object) that is "actively" putting
>   energy into the system; it wouldn't happen "automatically."

On the next page the author notes:

> Processes of heat transfer are further classified into three
>   categories, according to the mechanism involved. **Conduction** is the
>   transfer of heat by molecular contact: Fast-moving molecules bump into
>   slow-moving molecules, giving up some of their energy in the process.
>   **Convection** is the bulk motion of a gas or liquid, usually driven by the tendency of warmer material to expand and rise in a
>   gravitational field. **Radiation** is the emission of electromagnetic
>   waves, mostly infrared for objects at room temperature but including
>   visible light for hotter objects like the filament of a lightbulb or
>   the surface of the sun.

Although it's not spelled out here, I believe energy transfer via radiation only counts as "heat" if it's [blackbody radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) emitted solely due to the object's temperature; later on the book notes that increasing an object's temperature in a microwave oven would count as "work" rather than "heat", for example. An additional subtlety is that technically all transfers of energy between molecules at ordinary temperatures (below those of nuclear reactions) are due to electromagnetic interactions between them and might technically be types of "energy transfer via radiation", but presumably Schroeder is using "radiation" to talk about cases where energy is exchanged between systems even though there is a macroscopic separation between them.

As for temperature, the equipartition theorem does say that for a collection of molecules that each have a number of "quadratic degrees of freedom" (meaning the energy is proportional to the square of some velocity, or the square of the separation between the molecules in the case of one type of potential energy), each degree of freedom will on average contain an energy $(1/2)kT$, so the total "thermal energy" in a system of N molecules that each have f degrees of freedom is $U_{thermal} = N (f/2) kT$. The book notes on p. 15 that this thermal energy doesn't include all forms of energy:

> First of all, the quantity $U_{thermal}$ is almost never the *total*
>   energy of the system; there's also "static" energy that doesn't change
>   as you change the temperature, such as energy stored in chemical bonds
>   or the rest energies ($mc^2$) of all the particles in the system. So
>   it's safest to apply the equipartition theorem only to *changes* in
>   energy when the temperature is raised or lowered, and to avoid phase
>   transformations and other reactions in which bonds between particles
>   may be broken.

For a gas consisting of molecules that are each made up of only a single atom, the only degrees of freedom are translations on three independent spatial axes, each of which can contain some kinetic energy. For a gas of diatomic molecules there can be additional degrees of freedom beyond the three translational ones, though. There are two rotational degrees of freedom which can also contain kinetic energy--rotation along the axis joining the two molecules doesn't "count", the book says this is "for reasons having to do with quantum mechanics", but rotation along two orthogonal axes does. And the molecule can also vibrate, the two atoms changing distance along the axis joining them like two balls connected by a spring, so there is one additional degree of freedom that can contain kinetic energy from this vibration, and another which can contain varying *potential* energy as the bond between the atoms is stretched and compressed, the potential being proportional to the square of the separation like a spring. So, a diatomic molecule can have up to 7 degrees of freedom, although there is a further complication in that at certain temperatures the collisions between molecules may not be violent enough for them to exchange energy on certain degrees of freedom--as the book says on p. 16:

> However, at room temperature many vibrational degrees of freedom do
>   *not* contribute to a molecule's thermal energy. Again, the explanation lies in quantum mechanics, as we will see in Chapter 3. So
>   air molecules ($N_2$ and $O_2$), for instance, have only five degrees
>   of freedom, not seven, at room temperature. At higher temperatures,
>   the vibrational modes *do* eventually contribute. We say these modes
>   are "frozen out" at room temperature; evidently, collisions with other
>   molecules are sufficiently violent to make air molecule rotate, but
>   hardly ever violent enough to make it vibrate.

The temperature when different degrees of freedom become active can be determined by measuring how the [heat capacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) of a substance varies with temperature; the book notes on p. 28 that heat capacity should really be termed "energy capacity", since the heat capacity at constant volume $C_V$ is defined as the rate at which the internal energy changes as the temperature increases, $\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}$, which can be measured by adding a small known amount of energy and seeing how the temperature changes. For a system with only quadratic degrees of freedom where $U_{thermal} = N (f/2) kT$, you can see the heat capacity at constant volume will thus be $N(f/2)k$, and thus by measuring heat capacity as a function of temperature you can see when f increases, as shown in the diagram below from [this page](https://www.ux1.eiu.edu/~cfadd/1360/21KineticTheory/Equipart.html):

[image]

The above is just for a gas, p. 16 notes the following about degrees of freedom for solids and liquids:

> In a solid, each atom can vibrate in three perpendicular directions,
>   so for each atom there are six degrees of freedom (three for kinetic
>   energy and three for potential energy) ... Again, however, some of the
>   degrees of freedom may be "frozen out" at room temperature.
>
> Liquids are more complicated than either gases or solids. You can
>   generally use the formula $\frac{3}{2} kT$ to find the average
>   translational kinetic energy of molecules in a liquid, but the
>   equipartition theorem doesn't work for the rest of the thermal energy,
>   because the intermolecular potential energies are not nice quadratic
>   functions.

So to sum up, temperature is proportional to average translational kinetic energy along each of the 3 spatial axes for a gas of monoatomic molecules, but for molecules with more atoms or for solids it's proportional to the average "thermal energy" which includes non-translational kinetic energy (rotation, vibration) and potential energy; and if some degrees of freedom are non-quadratic, as in a liquid, there is no such simple relation between temperature and total internal energy.

The more fundamental definition of temperature in statistical mechanics is that it is the inverse of the rate that the *entropy* S changes as the internal energy U changes--if the volume V and particle number N is kept fixed, temperature is defined by the equation $\frac{1}{T} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial U}$ (in cases where N and/or V are not the quantities held fixed, you can use the "fundamental equation of thermodynamics", equation 5.1 on p. 2 of [this pdf](http://puccini.che.pitt.edu/~karlj/Classes/CHE2101/Shell/Ch5_The_fundamental_equation.pdf), to relate temperature to other quantities). This means that *by definition* the entropy of an isolated pair of systems will always increase when heat flows out of the hotter one and into the colder one, and entropy will reach a maximum when they have both reached the same temperature--see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/162303/59406) for more on this point.

Answer (score 3):

Object don't posses heat. They posses internal energy.

Heat, like work, is a transfer of energy and is a property of a process or interaction not of an object.

Comment: Could you provide further elaboration? I'm afraid I can't quite conceptualize your answer.

Comment: you asked for a concise way of defining accurately ;)

Comment: "heat" is a verb, not a noun

Comment: @VatsalManot The definition you gave above for "heat" doesn't belong to the word heat. It is a decent first pass at a definition of "internal energy". Heat is not a word that describes a property of an object; it describes a parameter or property of an interaction. Heat is an amount of energy *transferred* in an interaction. This distinction also applies to the word "work" in mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer states, objects don't posses heat. Heat is the actual amount of energy transferred from an object to another.

The typical case is when you have two objects $A,B$ at different temperature in contact, $T_A>T_B$. Then, it means as you say that the average energy of $A$ is bigger than the average energy of $B$. This induces some of the extra energy of $A$ to be *somehow* transferred to $B$: this extra energy transferred is the heat; this process will happen until $T_A=T_B$. Notice that the amount of heat transferred is related with the difference of temperatures (the *average* KE), not with the difference of energies (the *total* KE).